# Find Students who have registered in selected subject by Dropdown in php

Tags: php, sql, join

```
StudentID | SubCode | SubName
-------------------------------
   1          1       Math
   1          2       Science
   1          3       English
   2          1       Math
   2          2       Science
   3          2       Science
   4          1       Math
   4          3       English
```

This is my subject table.

How can I find students who have registered as following

1. Students who have registered in only Maths NOT in English and Science
2. Students who have registered In Maths And English NOT Science
3. Students who have registered In Science And Maths And English

in a single SQL query.

I tried as this way

```
    SELECT DISTINCT  
    `stud_id` FROM  `subj_assign` 
WHERE  
   `subj_id` =  '1,2'
   AND STATUS =  '1'
ORDER BY  
   `subj_assign`.`stud_id` ASC
```

AND Also This way tried but Not Working

```
   SELECT stud_id FROM subj_assign GROUP BY stud_id 
   HAVING Count(CASE WHEN subj_id = '1' AND 
       status='1' THEN 1 END) = 1 AND  
   Count(CASE WHEN `subj_id` = '2' AND 
       status='1' THEN 1 END) = 1
```

Comment: If i understood ur question correctly, r u asking - when u select a option in select box the results of that particular subject should be viewed ??
to achieve that, better use AJAX, send an AJAX request on selecting an option in the dropdown...

Comment: ajax is already working but sql query is not returning the right answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its rum for me. may be its help for you also.

```
SELECT stud_id FROM subj_assign GROUP BY stud_id 
   HAVING Count(CASE WHEN subj_id = '1' AND 
       status='1' THEN 1 END) = 1 AND  
   Count(CASE WHEN `subj_id` = '2' AND 
       status='1' THEN 1 END) = 1
```

then compare with total subject of student and filtered subjects with condition

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT
(SELECT DISTINCT StudentID FROM subject WHERE SubName = 'Math' AND StudentID NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT StudentID FROM subject WHERE SubName IN ('English', 'Science')) AS STUD_ONLY_IN_MATHS,
(SELECT DISTINCT StudentID FROM subject WHERE SubName in ('Math', 'English') AND StudentID NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT StudentID FROM subject WHERE SubName IN ('Science')) AS STUD_IN_MATHS_AND_ENGLISH,
(SELECT DISTINCT StudentID FROM subject WHERE SubName in ('Math', 'English', 'Science') AS STUD_IN_MATHS_ENGLISH_SCIENCE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the table with the table itself grouped by StudentID. That way you'll be able to test the number of rows and the SubCode at the same time.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tmp.StudentID
FROM subj_assign tmp JOIN (SELECT StudentID, COUNT(*) as total
                           FROM subj_assign
                           GROUP BY StudentID) tmpG on tmp.StudentID = tmpG.StudentID
WHERE (tmp.SubCode = 1 and total = 1) --Only Math
OR (total = 2 and SubCode != 2) --No Science
OR total = 3 --Math, English, Science
```